# how to pass Request data into Mailable in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.3

I cannot understand how to pass Request data to mail using new Mailable feature of Laravel 5.3
Using the code below I got error that variable $request is not defined.

web.php

```
Route::get('/',                 ['as' => 'home',        'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
Route::get('/callback',         ['as' => 'callback.show',   'uses' => 'PostController@callbackshow']);
Route::post('/callback',        ['as' => 'callback.send',   'uses' => 'PostController@callbacksend']);
```

Controllers\PostController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Mail\Callback;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class PostController extends Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function callbackshow() 
    {
        return view('callback');   
    }

    public function callbacksend(Request $request) 
    {
        $email = new Callback($request);
        \Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->send($email);
    }
```

Mail\Callback.php

```
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Callback extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request->all();
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.callback');
    }
}
```

emails\callback.blade.php

```
Name: {{ $request->name }}<br>
Email :  {{ $request->email }}<br>
```

Here is the error

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
2/2 ErrorException in 76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php line 2: Undefined variable: request (View: D:\OpenServer\domains\blog2\resources\views\emails\callback.blade.php)

    in 76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php line 2
    at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '0') in PhpEngine.php line 44
    at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('D:\OpenServer\domains\blog2\storage\framework\views/76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
    at CompilerEngine->get('D:\OpenServer\domains\blog2\resources\views/emails/callback.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in View.php line 149
    at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
    at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
    at View->render() in Mailer.php line 430
    at Mailer->getView('emails.callback', array('connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in Mailer.php line 310
    at Mailer->addContent(object(Message), 'emails.callback', null, null, array('connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in Mailer.php line 186
    at Mailer->send('emails.callback', array('connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null), object(Closure)) in Mailable.php line 117
    at Mailable->send(object(Mailer)) in Mailer.php line 173
    at Mailer->send(object(Callback)) in MailableMailer.php line 99
    at MailableMailer->send(object(Callback)) in PostController.php line 24
    at PostController->callbacksend(object(Request))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(PostController), 'callbacksend'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
    at Controller->callAction('callbacksend', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(PostController), 'callbacksend') in Route.php line 190
    at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
    at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

1/2 ErrorException in 76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php line 2: Undefined variable: request

    in 76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php line 2
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined variable: request', 'D:\OpenServer\domains\blog2\storage\framework\views\76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php', '2', array('__path' => 'D:\OpenServer\domains\blog2\storage\framework\views/76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message)), 'obLevel' => '0', '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in 76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php line 2
    at include('D:\OpenServer\domains\blog2\storage\framework\views\76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
    at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('D:\OpenServer\domains\blog2\storage\framework\views/76aac56b59bc685390113940ddc975544836b896.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
    at CompilerEngine->get('D:\OpenServer\domains\blog2\resources\views/emails/callback.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in View.php line 149
    at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
    at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
    at View->render() in Mailer.php line 430
    at Mailer->getView('emails.callback', array('connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in Mailer.php line 310
    at Mailer->addContent(object(Message), 'emails.callback', null, null, array('connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in Mailer.php line 186
    at Mailer->send('emails.callback', array('connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null), object(Closure)) in Mailable.php line 117
    at Mailable->send(object(Mailer)) in Mailer.php line 173
    at Mailer->send(object(Callback)) in MailableMailer.php line 99
    at MailableMailer->send(object(Callback)) in PostController.php line 24
    at PostController->callbacksend(object(Request))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(PostController), 'callbacksend'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
    at Controller->callAction('callbacksend', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(PostController), 'callbacksend') in Route.php line 190
    at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
    at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue like this

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Callback extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $input;


    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->input = $request->all();

        if (empty($this->input['email'])) { $this->input['email'] = 'admin@site.ru'; }
    }


    public function build()
    {

            return $this->subject('Обратный звонок с сайта')
                        ->view('emails.callback')
                        ->cc($this->input['email'], $this->input['name'])
                        ->replyTo($this->input['email'], $this->input['name']);

    }
}
```